# Most elegant way of updating comments in a rails blog app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly standard blog app with the usual post and comments controller/models along with a user model for leaving comments.

So in the user model I have

```
has_many :comments
```

And in the the comments model

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

All very straight forward.

In the app I'm creating I want the comments to act a little differently. When the user leaves a comment for the first time then I will create a new comment. However I only want to allow one comment per post per user. If the user tries to leave another comment then we should only update the existing comment.

To do this I have added a this to the user model

```
has_many :posts, :through => :comment
```

And in the Posts controller I have the following in the show action.

```
if post = current_user.posts.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  @comment = post.comments.find_by_user_id(current_user)
else
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

This works in that it checks if the user already made a comment on this post and if so then it will result in an update to the comment rather than a new one posted.

But, the above code doesn't sit right with me. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: By "update the existing comment", do you mean replace the content of their comment with the new content, or merge the two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing this is fine, but you should move the logic into the model.  I also suggest adding some validation using `validates_uniqueness_of`.

In Post you could do:

```
has_many :comments do 
    def find_or_build_for_user(user)
        find_by_user_id(current_user.id) || self.comment.build(:user => user)
    end
end
```

Then in your controller you'd do:

```
@comment = post.comments.find_or_build_for_user(current_user)
```

The above uses association extensions, you can read more about them here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

I'm not sure if the above will work as is as I haven't tested it, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's perfect. I never knew about association extensions, very useful. Thanks.

Comment: They can be very useful, but try not to overuse them.  You can also put them in a separate module and use the :extend option on the association.  Remember keep your controller skinny and your models fat! (http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model).